# Recording of training video call

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Ubuntu 15.04 (soon to be 15.10).

we will be doing some video conferencing training calls soon and would like to record them.  I believe this can be done using Pulse Audio Control and gtk-recordmydesktop.

Using the "Monitor" feature I can record audio, but I can't also simultaneously capture input from my microphone.

So Basically I need help to:

Microphone Input

- -> Video Conference App
- -> gtk-recordmydesktop

Video Conference App Output

- -> speakers/headphones
- -> gtk-recordmydesktop

Bonus points if *only* sounds from the Video Conference App are sent to gtk-recordmydesktop, with system sounds and sounds from other apps only being sent to speakers/headphones, but not to gtk-recordmydesktop.